# Infinite subsequence of prime numbers with simple formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, soft-question

There are many examples of finite subsequences of primes. The most famous is probably the Euler polynomial
$$x^2+x+41$$
But is there at least one simple formula for an infinite subsequence of primes in the entire history of mankind?

Comment: @Andreas one has to define "simple" as for example I do not think the formula in the Mills constant qualifies as simple as it grows way too fast; the answer imho is no, there is no such formula at least so far

Comment: @Conrad, ok, thanks, will remove my comments presently.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

Comment: @Andreas - I think it is fine to live them as that may be what the OP wants as again that word "simple" to me is unuseful - it is just an opinion that all the formulas say on Wikipedia are far from "simple" in the way meant, and I definitely accept that others can have a different opinion

Comment: @Conrad I think the more serious problem with Mills primes from OP's point of view is that we have no way of calculating the Mills constant other than finding the primes and then reverse-engineering it.  It's much less impressive to say $\lfloor A^{3^n} \rfloor$ is always prime if you can't tell me what $A$ is.

Comment: In 1650, Fermat incorrectly conjectured the formula $2^{2^n}+1$

Comment: Hint: all odd numbers, as the result of subtracting 2 or 4 from any prime greater than 3, are divisible by 3.

Comment: In short, no. For one variable, the only solved case is degree $1$. For two variables, the best known result is that $a^2+b^4$ with integers $a,b$ produces infinite many primes. The prime genrating polynomial with $26$ variables has no practical merit, and Mills constant has already been mentioned.

Comment: We still do not have a method to construct efficiently (that is without finding a candidate with trial division and testing it) ANY not yet known large prime. Fortunately, a test upto $200-300$ digits can be done within a second (or perhaps less), but for several thousand digits (say 7k digits) , finding a new prime requires some effort. And for say 40k digits, it is a considerable task.

Comment: @TomKern Yes, he was just too lazy to even test the fifth term, which Euler detected to be composite. It now seems that $F_4$ is the largest Fermat prime , although this problem is open , there could be infinite many Fermat primes , but everything speaks for finite many. Currently, $F_{33}$ is the largest unknown case. Should it be a prime, it will take quite a while to show that.